# WooCommerce Import Suite does not import all products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Good afternoon!

I am using WooCommerce Import Suite to move products (most of them variable) from one site to another. But at this point I get the following errors, how can I fix it?

[Open Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYDgV.png)

I have tried to optimise the images on the source site with Smush and increased the memory limit via wp-config.php on the target site.

Comment: Please share the plugin link and possible logs

Comment: The link is as follows:
https://woocommerce.com/es-es/products/product-csv-import-suite/
The logs are the ones in the image.

Comment: Please try import export suite for woocomnerce and share if any issues